# I get const_iterator instead of iterator from std::set

Tags: c++, containers, const-iterator

I have the following code which does not compile at all.
It says that I cannot convert `const Node` to `Node&` but `Node` is not `const` nor methods of `A` refer to a `const this` nor `std::set` is const.

Where am I wrong?

```
#include <set>
#include <string>

struct Node
{
    std::string name;
};

struct NodeNameComparator
{
    using is_transparent = void;
    bool operator()(const Node &a, const std::string &b) const { return a.name < b; }
    bool operator()(const std::string &a, const Node &b) const { return a < b.name; }
    bool operator()(const Node &a, const Node &b) const { return a.name < b.name; }
};


struct A
{
    std::set<Node, NodeNameComparator> nodeset;
    Node &add_or_get_node(const std::string &name)
    {
        std::set<Node, NodeNameComparator>::iterator it = nodeset.template find(name);
        // IT WORKS BUT IT IS A WORKAROUND.
        //return it == nodeset.end() ? const_cast<Node&>(*(nodeset.insert(*new Node{name}).first)) : const_cast<Node&>(*it);
        //ERROR!!!
        return it == nodeset.end() ? *(nodeset.insert(*new Node{name}).first) : *it;
    };
};

int main() { return 0; }
```

Comment: `std::set` iterator is constant iterator [by design](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set#Member_types). `std::set` keeps its elements in the sorted order internally. If you could modify set elements, it would be possible to break this invariant externally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::set` is not just a set of elements, it is a sorted set of unique elements. Elements of `std::set` are immutable by design, so that you cannot break `std::set` invariant by modifying its elements. That's the reason why `std::set::iterator` and `std::set::const_iterator` are both constant iterators.

Cppreference on `std::set` [reads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set#Member_types):

```
Member type       Definition 

iterator          Constant LegacyBidirectionalIterator
const_iterator    Constant LegacyBidirectionalIterator
```

See also [this LWG issue](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue103):

> Keys in an associative container are immutable. ... For associative containers where the value type is the same as the key type, both `iterator` and `const_iterator` are constant iterators.
>
> **Rationale**: ... if elements were mutable, there would be no compile-time way to detect of a simple user oversight which caused ordering to be modified. There was a report that this had actually happened in practice, and had been painful to diagnose. If users need to modify elements, it is possible to use mutable members or `const_cast`.

Comment: Interesting. Even if I have `const` the `Node::name` which does the sorting. So, my question really does not answer my original problem: How can create a `std::map<std::string, Node> name_to_node` without duplicating `Node::name`? I really need to change all members of `Node` except `Node::name` which can be `const`. Is the `const_cast` ok, if I know that `Node::name` never change?

Comment: @Chameleon, according to my understanding, as far as you don't change the ordering of elements imposed by `NodeNameComparator`, you can cast constness away with `const_cast`.